# Renew ssl cert but only have private key and fullchain file

Tags: lets-encrypt, ssl-certificate-renewal

Is it possible to renew certs from letsencrypt with just the private key and fullchain file?

If not, can one just remove all the letsencrypt files and .well-known directory and apply for new certification using certbot or other programs? Or would I need to wait for the current cert to expire?

A small company approached me with this issue of not being able to renew their certs. I found everything to be a mess to where I'm not sure how it was done in the past.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can, but it might be a bit tricky
2. this is faster way - remove let's encrypt certs and use certbot to generate new cert. you don't have to wait for it to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is better to simply generate a new cert. I have personally not had great luck renewing and fail to see the advantage over